# Solution verification: solving $\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt{x-5}+1=0$

Tags: solution-verification

I solved the following equation, and I just want to be sure I did it right.

This is the procedure:

$$
\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt{x-5}+1=0\\
\sqrt{x-4}=\sqrt{x-5}-1\\
\text{squaring both sides gives me:}\\
(\sqrt{x-4})^2=(\sqrt{x-5}-1)²\\
x-4=(\sqrt{x-5})²-\sqrt{x-5}+1\\
x-4=x-5-\sqrt{x-5}+1\\
x-4=x-4-\sqrt{x-5}\\
\text{substracting x, and adding 4 to both sides}\\
0=-\sqrt(x-5)\\
\text{switching both sides}\\
\sqrt{x-5}=0\\
\text{sqaring both sides}\\
x-5=0\\
x=5\\
\text{When I place 5 in the equation, I get:}\\
\sqrt{5-4}-\sqrt{5-5}+1=0\\
\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{0}+1=0\\
1-0+1=0\\
2=0\\
\text{this means that the equation dosent have any solution, right??}\\
$$
Any advice and suggestion is helpful.

Thanks!!!

Comment: No solutions exist.

Comment: $$(\sqrt{x}-1)^2 = x - 2\sqrt{x} + 1$$
and you seem to have dropped the 2...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to see it, is take both square roors to the other side and square, to get
$$
\begin{split}
1 &= (x-5)-(x-4) - 2\sqrt{(x-5)(x-4)}\\
2 + 2\sqrt{(x-5)(x-4)} &=  0\\
1 + \sqrt{(x-5)(x-4)} &=  0\\
\end{split}
$$
but $\sqrt{\ldots} \geq 0$ so this is impossible...

Comment: Can you explain me, how do you know that $\sqrt{...} < 0$. Thanks.

Comment: @depecheSoul : He doesn't, his last equation implies $\sqrt{...} = -1$ which is impossible.

Comment: $\sqrt4=\sqrt(\pm 2)^2=\pm 2$

Comment: @RealHilbert If you plug in any real value for $x$ into $\sqrt{(x-5)(x-4)}$, you will never get anything negative out...

Comment: Got it thanks everybody!!

Comment: check $x=\frac{9+\sqrt5}{2}$ you may get -1

Comment: @RealHilbert when a equation involving the function $\sqrt{x}$ is given, it's often implicit that one of the positive or negative value is chosen for all square roots. In both cases, it's correct to conclude that the square root appearing in last equation is positive.

Comment: @RealHilbert We are not dealing with *complex* curves, there are no branches. $\sqrt{x} > 0$ by definition...

Answer (score 4):

Note that the expansion of $(\sqrt{x - 5} - 1)^2 = (\sqrt{x - 5})^2 - {\bf 2}\sqrt {x - 5} + 1$.

But that correction doesn't change the fact that indeed, no solution exists.

Comment: Needs another UV+1

Comment: @amWhy: Agreed, needs another UV +1

Answer (score 3):

It is easily seen that the equation $\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt{x-5}=-1$ has no solutions since $\sqrt{x-4}>\sqrt{x-5}$ for all $x>=5$.

Your method is correct but you made a mistake in going from step $3$ to step $4$. After correcting that, you will still reach the same conclusion that there are no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

The square root function is increasing on $[0,\infty)$, so
$$\sqrt{x-4} - \sqrt{x-5} \ge  0 $$
for all $x\ge 5.$  Hence the expression can never equal -1.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ \ \sqrt{z+1}+\sqrt{z}\, =:\, y\ $ times $\,(\sqrt{z+1}-\sqrt{z}\,=\,-1) \ \Rightarrow\  1 = -y\,$ contra $\, y > 0\ \ \ $ **QED**

Answer (score 1):

As $(x-4)-(x-5)=1$

$\displaystyle(\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt{x-5})(\sqrt{x-4}+\sqrt{x-5})=1$

As $\displaystyle\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt{x-5}=-1, \sqrt{x-4}+\sqrt{x-5}=-1$

Adding we get $\displaystyle\sqrt{x-4}=-1$ which is impossible as $\sqrt{x-1}\ge0$ for real $x$

Answer (score 1):

Set $a=\sqrt{x-4}$ and $b=\sqrt{x-5}$ for $-2\leq x\leq +2$. Equivalently we have $a^2=x-4$,  $b^2={x-5}$ for $-2\leq x\leq +2$. It's implies for $-2\leq x\leq +2$,
\begin{align}
a-b=-1 \implies & (a-b)(a+b)=-1\cdot(a+b)\\
       \implies & a^2-b^2=-(a+b)\\
       \implies & (x-4)-(x-5)=-(a+b)\\
       \implies & -1=-(a+b)\\
       \implies & a+b=+1.\\
\end{align}
The same calculations and similar implications $a+b=+1\implies a-b=+1$. Then $ x $ is a root of $a+b=-1$, if only if, 
\begin{cases}
a+b=&+1\\
a-b=&-1\\
\end{cases}
Here, $a=0$ and $b=1$ implies $a^2=x-4=0$ and $b^2={x-5}=1$. In both cases, $x\in\!\!\!\!\!/[-2,+2]$.
So the equation 
$$
\sqrt{x-4}-\sqrt{x-5}+1=0 
$$
has no solution.